# Select Multiple ids and Pass to controller at once

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Am tried to select multiple of `ids` from the concept of delete multiple ids, but am get the error and ids not passed

this is code i tried

```
  <button style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="btn btn-primary delete_all" data-url="{{ 
      url('receiveAllUnit') }}">Received All</button>
     $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#master').on('click', function(e) {
     if($(this).is(':checked',true))
     {
        $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);
     } else {
        $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);
     }
    });


    $('.delete_all').on('click', function(e) {


        var allVals = [];
        $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {
            allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });


        if(allVals.length <=0)
        {
            alert("Please select row.");
        }  else {


            var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to Receive All Units?");
            if(check == true){


                var join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");


                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).data('url'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data['success']) {
                            $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {
                                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                            });
                            alert(data['success']);
                        } else if (data['error']) {
                            alert(data['error']);
                        } else {
                            alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    }
                });


              $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) {
                  $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
              });
            }
        }
    });


    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        onConfirm: function (event, element) {
            element.trigger('confirm');
        }
    });


    $(document).on('confirm', function (e) {
        var ele = e.target;
        e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
            url: ele.href,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data['success']) {
                    $("#" + data['tr']).slideUp("slow");
                    alert(data['success']);
                } else if (data['error']) {
                    alert(data['error']);
                } else {
                    alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });


        return false;
    });
});
```

kindly can you show me how i can fetch those ids and passed to controller

am expect to update one column like this

```
 RotateDevice::whereIn([ ['DeviceId',$ids]
                                        ])
                              ->update([
                                'status'=>0,
                              ]);
```

Comment: You should provide only the shortest JS code needed to reproduce your problem. Also provide the controller method that is receiving this data, and the definition for the route pointing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ajax Call replace From

```js
data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,
```

To

```js
data: {ids:join_selected_values},
```

and in Controller

```php
$idsString=$request->input('ids');
$idsArray=explode(",",trim($idsString,','));//explode to split ids to array , and trim to ensure if ids received with , at the end or beginning of string. 
if(!empty($idsArray)){
     RotateDevice::whereIn('DeviceId',$idsArray)
          ->update(['status'=>0]);
}
```

Comment: am getting this error: `  "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\equalpoint\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,`

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/device/add_all_unit_rotate/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106